# org.netbeans.validation.api.builtin.Validators

Tags: validation

At current I have a login window for username and password. I'm using these validators for the fields

```
group.add(username, ValidationStrategy.ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION, Validators.NO_WHITESPACE);
group.add(password, ValidationStrategy.ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION, Validators.NO_WHITESPACE);
```

My issue is that the NO_WHITESPACE works at start as that the login button becomes active once you enter name but if remove name the button stays active. should the NO_WHITESPACE not kick in again?

Answer (score 1):

I enable/disable via ValidationUI as follows:

```
ValidationPanel vp = new ValidationPanel();        
ValidationGroup g = vp.getValidationGroup(); 

g.add(username, ValidationStrategy.ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION, Validators.NO_WHITESPACE);
g.add(password, ValidationStrategy.ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION, Validators.NO_WHITESPACE);    

g.addUI(new ValidationUI() {

   @Override
   public void clearProblem() {
      connectButton.setEnabled(true);
   }

   @Override
   public void setProblem(Problem prblm) {
      connectButton.setEnabled((prblm != null) && (prblm.isFatal()));
   }
});

g.validateAll();
```