# org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.ValidationGroup.add() - How to specify ValidationStrategy?

Tags: java, validation, netbeans

Previously I used netbeans ValidationAPI_v0.4 which supported :

```
org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.ValidationGroup group;
...
group.add(myTextField, ValidationStrategy.ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION, Validators.IP_ADDRESS);
```

With latest ValidationGroup API how to specify ValidationStrategy.ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION ?

I see in ValidationGroup an add() without the ValidationStrategy param :

```
public final <ComponentType,ValueType> void add(ComponentType comp,
                                 Validator<ValueType>... validators)
```

More info on simplevalidation at http://kenai.com/projects/simplevalidation/pages/Home

Javadoc API at http://mongkie.org/javadoc/org-mongkie-validation/org/netbeans/validation/api/ui/ValidationGroup.html#add%28ComponentType,%20org.netbeans.validation.api.Validator...%29

My old approach was used at e.g. [org.netbeans.validation.api.builtin.Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843235/org-netbeans-validation-api-builtin-validators/8228519#8228519)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION was the default.

There were lots of API changes between 0.4 and 0.9 version of simple validation API.

I used info from :

- http://kenai.com/projects/simplevalidation/forums/forum/topics/1963-API-Stabilization-and-Changes

and a looked at changes from a similar migration done at

- https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=204648 which references changeset http://hg.netbeans.org/main/rev/fa49e79eb900 Source at https://svn.kenai.com/svn/simplevalidation~src/trunk/

to better understand what had to be changed.