# Java: Simple Validation API Validation Strategy Change

Tags: java

This is in reference to the question posted at [org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.ValidationGroup.add() - How to specify ValidationStrategy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486028/org-netbeans-validation-api-ui-validationgroup-add-how-to-specify-validation)

I am trying to do something similar. Please guide me on what needs to be changed and where. I went through the given links but couldn't find the relevant info.

P.S.: Asking in a separate question because I can't comment on the original one due to lack of reputation points.

Regards

Uday

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows a lack of effort.

Comment: Please excuse me for my lack of effort but I am on it since last two days. While this API is excellent but there are no good documentation available where I can look for this kind of info. I wouldn't have posted this question had the answer to original question reflected what needs to be done.

Comment: Can you add relevant code and show what you have tried? It helps troubleshooting what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was required.

Check out the code from their repository (https://svn.kenai.com/svn/simplevalidation~src) and open ValidationAPI as a project in Netbeans (or whatever IDE you're using).

To change the default validation strategy you'll need to make the changes in ValidationGroup and SwingValidationGroup classes under org.netbeans.validation.api.ui and org.netbeans.validation.api.ui.swing respectively.

In these classes find ValidationStrategy.DEFAULT and replace it with the strategy you want (INPUT_VERIFIER, ON_FOCUS_LOSS, ON_CHANGE_OR_ACTION).

Build the project to generate a new jar and incorporate that jar in your own project.

That's it.